# Execute java from php - from cmd ok, from php not (windows)

Tags: java, php, localhost

I tried to run morfologik (java tool which I use to find the simplest form of the word http://kent.dl.sourceforge.net/project/morfologik/morfologik-stemming/1.9.0/) via php.

I have a problem... from windows cmd everything works fine:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\tag\morfologik>java -jar morfologik-tools-1.9.0-standalone.jar plstem -i lol.txt -ie UTF-8 -o lol2.txt
Input encoding: UTF-8
Output encoding: Cp1250
Processed 2 words in 0.003 seconds (667 words per second).
```

And the output file (defined in commad as: -o lol2.txt) looks as I expected

```
kota    kota    subst:sg:nom:f
kota    kot subst:sg:acc:m1
kota    kot subst:sg:acc:m2+subst:sg:gen:m1
kota    kot subst:sg:gen:m2
```

But when I tried to run this java program from php:

```
exec("java -jar C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\tag\\morfologik\\morfologik-tools-1.9.0-standalone.jar plstem -i lol.txt -ie UTF-8 -o lol2.txt 2>&1 ", $result);
print_r( $result );
```

I received the message:

```
Array ( [0] => Nazwa 'java' nie jest rozpoznawana jako polecenie wewn�trzne lub zewn�trzne, [1] => program wykonywalny lub plik wsadowy. )
// that means somewhere about: 'java' is not recognized as internal or external command, executable or batch file
```

I tried also(separately) 1) popen() , 2) shell_exec() , 3) passthru() , 4) system()

```
// 1)
$handle = popen("java -jar C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\tag\\morfologik\\morfologik-tools-1.9.0-standalone.jar plstem -i lol.txt -ie UTF-8 -o lol2.txt 2>&1", 'r');
while(!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle);
    echo "$buffer<br/>\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
pclose($handle);

// 2)   
echo shell_exec('java -jar C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\tag\\morfologik\\morfologik-tools-1.9.0-standalone.jar plstem -i lol.txt -ie UTF-8 -o lol2.txt 2>&1 ');

// 3)
passthru("java -jar C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\tag\\morfologik\\morfologik-tools-1.9.0-standalone.jar plstem -i lol.txt -ie UTF-8 -o lol2.txt 2>&1 ");

// 4) 
system("java -jar C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\tag\\morfologik\\morfologik-tools-1.9.0-standalone.jar plstem -i lol.txt -ie UTF-8 -o lol2.txt 2>&1 ");
```

Everythime I received fail.

After a lot of fails, I think, I should reconfigure my environment variables(screenshot):
http://s430.photobucket.com/user/Dariusz_Majchrzak/media/aaa_zps4ocsosyy.png.html 
but still not works. What am I doing wrong?

The goal: Using the php, I wanna get the output file, which I defined in this command as lol2.txt

```
java -jar C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\tag\\morfologik\\morfologik-tools-1.9.0-standalone.jar plstem -i lol.txt -ie UTF-8 -o lol2.txt
```

I working on localhost using Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64-bit, xampp 5.5.19 with: Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.19

____EXTENDED:
info about java

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\tag\morfologik>cd c:\

c:\>java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

And infos about law and permissions to the folders(screenshot):
http://s430.photobucket.com/user/Dariusz_Majchrzak/media/bbb_zpsfyp922ra.png.html

Comment: Is there any Java installed on your computer or is it perhaps bundled with this morfologik tool itself? What do you get when you type 'java -version' in any other directory than c:\xampp\htdocs\tag\morfologik  ?

Comment: Looks like I installed Java properly. I extended main post with this info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add java executable to windows PATH environmental variable. The detailed instructions you can find here:

https://www.java.com/pl/download/help/path.xml